# Cannot detect unmanaged memory allocations in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, new-operator, profiler

I want to determine the source of huge memory consumption of my app. My application is eating a lot of virtual memory (VM column in task manager or private bytes in VMMap)

My application is .net service but it uses C# wrappers around C++ objects.

I tried Red Gate Ants Memory profiler but it counts only managed objects and does not count memory allocated by unmanaged C++ new operator (which is simply calling Virtual Alloc).

Another problem with managed memory profiler is that does not allow to trace call graph - see picture below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what settings are you using in the RedGate memory profiler ? with that I found sometime ago even a memory leak in a 3rdparty library which was using unmanaged allocations...

Comment: Why not use a native profiler for the unmanaged bits?

Comment: leppie, can you recommend one?

Comment: @Captain - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818673/memory-profiler-for-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26798). It will track C# and C++ objects.